# SQL Open XML Format - Value Key="Col1"

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

Is there any way to get the XML output from an OPEN XML query to look like this

```
<TableName>
<Value Key="Col1">Col1 Value</Value>
<Value Key="Col2">Col2 Value</Value>
<Value Key="Col3">Col3 Value</Value>
etc.......
```

E.g.

```
<FooBar>
<Value Key="Name">Mr Woo</Value>
<Value Key="Age">22</Value>
<Value Key="Location">The Moon</Value>
</FooBar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59bb2/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```sql
create table T
(
  Name varchar(10),
  Age int,
  Location varchar(10)
);

insert into T values('Mr Woo', 22, 'The Moon');
```

**Query 1**:

```sql
select 'Name' as [Value/@Key],
       Name as [Value],
       null,
       'Age' as [Value/@Key],
       Age as [Value],
       null,
       'Location' as [Value/@Key],
       Location as [Value]
from T
for xml path('FooBar')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/59bb2/1/0)**:

```xml
<FooBar>
  <Value Key="Name">Mr Woo</Value>
  <Value Key="Age">22</Value>
  <Value Key="Location">The Moon</Value>
</FooBar>
```